# the most efficient way to separate string

Tags: c#, string, optimization, split

I have this string:

"B82V16814133260"

what would be the most efficient way to get two strings out of it:

left part String: "B82V"
rigth part string: "16814133260"

The rule is this: take all numbers on the right side and create string out of them, then take the reminder and place it into another string.

This is my solution, but it is too bulky! How to do it short and efficient?

```
        String leftString = "";
        String rightString="";

        foreach (char A in textBox13.Text.Reverse())
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(A))
            {
                rightString += A;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        char[] arr = rightString.ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);

        rightString=new string(arr);
        leftString = textBox13.Text.Replace(rightString, "");
```

Comment: what do you mean saying `efficient` ? Efficient in memory or in performance?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your solution 'too bulky'? It looks to be a good length of a function to me.

Comment: I'll post the relevant Regex, but I swear to god if someone else posts it first...

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have at the moment?

Comment: Well; I mean more compact and clean and in terms of perfomance.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv all of the string concatenation is rather inefficent.  StringBuilder would help, but a regex could do it all with one pass and one copy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This yields what you're expecting:

```
var given = "B82V16814133260";
var first = given.TrimEnd("0123456789".ToCharArray());
var rest = given.Substring(first.Length);

Console.Write("{0} -> {1} -- {2}", given, first, rest);
//  B82V16814133260 -> B82V -- 16814133260
```

Comment: +1: While theoretically scanning the string until `ch < '0' || ch > '9'` and then splitting on the index sounds like the fastest, it would take a scientific app to tell the difference (maybe).

Comment: An elegant solution. I didn't know about TrimEnd.

Comment: An improvement on this would be to use the fact that '0'..'9' are consecutive to improve performance. E.g. var index = given.Last(ch => ch >= '0' && ch <= '9');

Comment: @danny, unfortunately that would disqualify him from using TrimEnd, which is really the central point of his answer.

Comment: @CMP I know, however, using Substring() twice could do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the other answer is probably better, but I wrote this anyway, so I'm posting it:

Needs:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Code:

```
string str = "B82V16814133260";
string[] match = Regex.match(str, @"^([\d\w]+?\w)(\d+)$").Groups;
string left = match[1];
string right = match[2];
```

Comment: it is also a very nice solution!

Comment: @walkerneo just a fun fact, running regex for this (Compiled regex too, release build) took 1605.3 seconds, or 856.4 times longer) So if speed is 'efficient', regex isn't 'efficient'.

Comment: @payo, Alright, thanks, I assumed as much. Should his requirements change though, so that the string doesn't end in only digits, this will be easier to modify. I can't tell if that's possible in his situation, and for all I know, those strings will always be in the same format, but still, you never know.

Comment: BTW!!! I hope people reading this do realize that 1605.3 seconds is based on the test I wrote (comparing runtimes to other answers in this same post. I think Walkemeo knew that, but visitors later may not realize that. Clearly, running the regex ONCE will finish in < .2ms.

Answer (score 3):

This should be very fast:

```
int index = text.Length - 1;
while (index >= 0 && Char.IsDigit(text[index]))
{
    index--;
}
string left = text.Substring(0, index + 1);
string right = text.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: Very fast in comparison to what?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: there is no unnecessary allocations of the `string`, `reversing` of the string and no `array` allocation. *Should* be faster.

Comment: Actually I would choose this answer most likely like a correct one, cause it's clearer and *should* be faster then the most voted, even if should admit that the most voted is definitely "cuter".

Comment: @Tigran Thanks! The favourite answer is really an interesting one, I wouldn't ever think about that.

Answer (score 2):

I read 'most efficient' as 'fastest'.

I wrote a quick test with a long string, running 10 million times.

Austin's solution to use `TrimEnd` ran in 4.649s

My solution ran in 1.927 seconds

```
    int j = given.Length - 1;

    for (; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      char c = given[j];
      if (c < '0' || c > '9')
      {
        break;
      }
    }

    var first = given.Substring(0, j + 1);
    var rest = given.Substring(j + 1);
```

Note that my builds were not debug (in debug, my solution is slower, but that is because TrimEnd is not running in debug bits). So, if you are running my code in your application, and are building debug, it'll be slower.

Answer (score 1):

I like linq.

```
    var s = "B82V16814133260";
    var lastNonNumeric = s.Reverse().Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).FirstOrDefault();
    var index = s.LastIndexOf(lastNonNumeric);
    var secondString = s.Substring(index + 1);
    var firstString = s.Substring(0, index+1);
```

Probably not the best or most robust solution, but it works for your test string.

Comment: Reverse would be a waste of effort since you do not need to keep the reversed result. s.Last(ch => '0' <= ch && ch <= '9') would be faster.

Comment: I agree. Still not as good as Austin's solution, so I won't bother editing it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string Source = textBox13.Text;

 for (i = Source.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
 {
      if (! Char.IsNumber(Source[i])
         break;
 }

 string leftString = Source.Left(i+1);
 string rightString = Source.Right(i+1,Source.Length-i-1);
```